# How to display specific JSON data from an API

Tags: javascript, node.js

> I'm using got for requests.

Code:

```
const response = await got(`https://airapi.airly.eu/v2/measurements/installation?installationId=204`, {
        headers: {
            apikey: `API_KEY`
        },
        json: true
    });

console.log(response.body.current.values);
```

Output:

```
[ { name: 'PM1', value: 20.72 },
  { name: 'PM25', value: 32.43 },
  { name: 'PM10', value: 61.22 },
  { name: 'PRESSURE', value: 1028.46 },
  { name: 'HUMIDITY', value: 91.59 },
  { name: 'TEMPERATURE', value: 10.87 } ]
```

Now, I want to display it to the user in this format:

```
PM1: 20.72 µg/m3 
PM25: 32.43 µg/m3 
PM10: 61.22 µg/m3
```

My question is: What's the best way to do that? In the future, I also want to use a library like https://www.chunqiuyiyu.com/ervy/, so it would be nice to have this data somehow separated. I hope that I've made myself clear :)

Comment: Display it to the user where? In the console, in the browser somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Envy uses a specific structure for its data, so you first need to convert your existing data:

```
const data = arr.map(el => ({ ...el, key: el.name }));
```

Then you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the elements and join them with line breaks afterwards, printing them to the console.

Demo:

```js
const arr = [{"name":"PM1","value":20.72},{"name":"PM25","value":32.43},{"name":"PM10","value":61.22},{"name":"PRESSURE","value":1028.46},{"name":"HUMIDITY","value":91.59},{"name":"TEMPERATURE","value":10.87}];

// create an envy structure from the original data using `map`
const data = arr.map(el => ({ ...el, key: el.name }));

// `map` over that data and return an array of strings
// separated by line breaks
const str = data.map(el => `${el.key}: ${el.value} µg/m3`).join('\n');

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this (without resorting to a library).  One way:

```js
let data = [ 
  { name: 'PM1', value: 20.72 },
  { name: 'PM25', value: 32.43 },
  { name: 'PM10', value: 61.22 },
  { name: 'PRESSURE', value: 1028.46 },
  { name: 'HUMIDITY', value: 91.59 },
  { name: 'TEMPERATURE', value: 10.87 }
];

data.forEach(v => console.log(`${v.name}: ${v.value} µg/m3`));
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do like

```
 var data = [ { name: 'PM1', value: 20.72 },
  { name: 'PM25', value: 32.43 },
  { name: 'PM10', value: 61.22 },
  { name: 'PRESSURE', value: 1028.46 },
  { name: 'HUMIDITY', value: 91.59 },
  { name: 'TEMPERATURE', value: 10.87 } ];


  $.each(data, function (i) {
   console.log(data[i].name+':'+data[i].value);
    });
```